# Open source document management (alternative to Microsoft Sharepoint)

Tags: open-source, document-management

I am looking for a open source application which will replace Microsoft Sharepoint.

Requirements:

- Open source
- Document management and storage system
- Revision history of all the files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Alfresco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfresco_(software)) is an open source document management system.

It is rather similar to Sharepoint.

Alfresco is easier to use by office workers than Subversion, especially because it does not have branches (Sharepoint also does not have branches).

Comment: ♦ Thanks for the wonderful suggestion. Alfresco is perfect for my requirements. Couldn't get proper support for India location. Do you have any leads?

Comment: Do you mean professional support? There are a dozen support partners in India alone: https://www.alfresco.com/partners

Answer (score 1):

I have used Subversion in industry for many years for version control of documents. There may be something better, but SVN is free and it lets us keep the documents with the code. Go for it.